# How to remove an item from a pre-existing list using a for loop and through the use of append?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Essentially what I'm trying to do is remove values within a list when a condition has been met.

The conditions are based upon the position of the value in the list, which is what remove_position stands for in the function definition. The code below is what I have so far and I'm using Python 3.6.0. The list in this case is from an external python file which imports the function from another python and is:

```
str_list5 = ['w', 'i', 'n', 'g']
new_list = list_function.remove_value(str_list5, 2)
print(new_list)
new_list = list_function.remove_value(str_list5, -1)
print(new_list)
new_list = list_function.remove_value(str_list5, 10)
print(new_list)
```

What I'm trying to do use the remove_position value above in an arithmetic function that will delete the item that corresponds to the function's result.

```
def remove_value(my_list, remove_position):
    newlist = []
    count = 0

    for item in my_list:
        if remove_position < count:
            newlist.remove(item)

        if remove_position > count:
            newlist.remove(item)

    return newlist
```

The output that I'm looking for is this:

```
remove_value Test
['w', 'i', 'g']
['i', 'n', 'g']
['w', 'i', 'n']
```

Comment: Using Python 3.6.0

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I want to be able to delete the items in the list depending on an arithmetic condition applied using the value of remove_position

Comment: Sorry about that, I added a little more detail to my previous explanation.

Comment: can you add your desired output ? Sorry i didn't get the logic behind your code.

Comment: @ChihebNexus yeah sure sorry, i'm still kinda new to the language please forgive

Comment: why `new_list = remove_value2(str_list5, -1)` should remove first element?

Comment: or it is supposed to remove last element?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov it isn't supposed to remove the last element, the remove_position value is supposed to be used in an equation which then deletes the "w" value as shown in the output I'm trying to get at.

Comment: i don't get it, how count should be changed? and why `-1` removes first element and `10` – the last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
my_list = ['w','i','n','g']

def remove_value(my_list, position):
    if position >= len(my_list):
        return my_list[:-1]
    elif position < 0:
        return my_list[1:]
    else:
        return my_list[:position] + my_list[position+1:]


# Test
remove_value(my_list, 2)
remove_value(my_list, -1)
remove_value(my_list, 10)
```

Output:

```
['w', 'i', 'g']
['i', 'n', 'g']
['w', 'i', 'n']
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, this helped a lot!

Comment: You can have a look at [List/tuple/string slicing](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) if you need more informations.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**: `list` objects are [mutable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mutable) and when you change them inside of a function – the original changes too, so if you use `list.remove` method in `remove_value` your `str_list5` loses element as well.

I advise you to create new object instead of mutating the old one.
We can write this

```
def remove_value(my_list, remove_position):
    result = []
    remove_position = min(max(remove_position, 0), len(my_list) - 1)
    for position, element in enumerate(my_list):
        if position == remove_position:
            continue
        result.append(element)
    return result
```

or using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
def remove_value(my_list, remove_position):
    remove_position = min(max(remove_position, 0), len(my_list) - 1)
    return [element
            for position, element in enumerate(my_list)
            if position != remove_position]
```

or following @ChihebNexus suggestion using `list` [slices](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice)

```
def remove_value(my_list, remove_position):
    remove_position = min(max(remove_position, 0), len(my_list) - 1)
    return my_list[0: remove_position] + my_list[remove_position + 1:]
```

So which one to choose? The last version looks more elegant to me.

## Tests

```
str_list5 = ['w', 'i', 'n', 'g']
new_list = remove_value(str_list5, 2)
print(new_list)
new_list = remove_value(str_list5, -1)
print(new_list)
new_list = remove_value(str_list5, 10)
print(new_list)
```

gives us

```
['w', 'i', 'g']
['i', 'n', 'g']
['w', 'i', 'n']
```

Comment: This definitely is a step in the right direction but I'm having trouble with the final two outputs using -1 and 10 as remove_position's value and was wondering how I can get around that.

Comment: @almight_vizzo: what logic lies behind `-1` and `10` as `remove_position`?

Comment: @almight_vizzo: how it should be changed to get valid position inside of `my_list`?

Comment: that's the thing, i wanted to see if there was a way to work around using such values that clearly don't correspond to the element number in the string through arithmetic

Comment: @almight_vizzo: i think i've finally understood the logic

Comment: i'm really sorry if you've been frustrated trying to understand what i've been trying to get at, do you know if it's possible to get around it using an arithmetic equation?

Comment: @almight_vizzo: without `if-else`?

Comment: yes, if possible, however if there is another solution using `if-else` that would also be appreciated

Comment: @almight_vizzo: added another version of position normalization

Comment: i appreciate the help, but is it possible to keep it  within one single function and not have to call upon another one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    def remove_value(my_list, remove_position):
    my_list.pop(remove_position)

    return my_list

str_list5 = ['w','i','n','g']
new_list = remove_value(str_list5, 2)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension is a good choice

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if your_condition]
```

specifically, you may want this

```
def remove_value(my_list, remove_position):
    return [my_list[i] for i in range(len(my_list)) if i != remove_position]
```